# Using CTE with a dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to use [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) to perform a dynamic pivot, but I want to use a CTE to get the initial data.

My query looks like this:

```
DECLARE  @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH dataSet (coDate, TransactionDate, TotalBalance, TransDate, collected)
AS 
(   *SELECT STATEMENT ) 


SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
    FROM dataSet c
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')


 set @query = 'SELECT coDate, ' + @cols + ' from 
        (
            select coDate
                , TotalBalance
                , collected
                , TransDate
            from dataSet
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
             SUM(collected)
            for category in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '


execute(@query)
```

And the error SQL gives me is Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'. I did try adding a semicolon and go as well as a comma before the SET statement, but this the first time I've used PIVOT so I'm not sure how CTE interacts with it.

Comment: I dont think you can use cte with dinamic pivot. Use cte to populate a temporal table, and use the temporal table in the pivot query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Temporal or temporary?

Comment: @dfundako all depend if you speak spanish or not ;)